# Swing JTextPane in javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm looking for a rich textarea in javafx. I have tried the RichTextFX component by Tomas Mikula but it is too buggy for my needs.

I was thinking whether it would be possible to plug in a swing JTextPane using the SwingNode class.

So far it actually works as in, I can see the text in the JTextPane and the JScrollPane around it even works. A mouselistener on the JTextPane also seems to be triggered correctly for mouse events but other than that...nothing works.

There is no cursor indicating the current position, no way to "click" with the mouse to change the position, select text,...

Key events simply don't arrive (using a keylistener)

Is it possible to use a JTextPane in javafx and if so, what am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [HTMLEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html)

Comment: I have a similar problem with a JPasswordField. I use this workaround at the moment. `node.setOnMouseReleased(event ->  node.requestFocus());` (node is your SwingNode).

Comment: Ah very nice! I can confirm that this fix also works for the JTextPane. In the meantime I have written a new rich text area control in pure javafx though but still nice to know :) If you can repeat your solution in an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I only know a workaround for this problem.
`node.setOnMouseReleased(event -> node.requestFocus());`
 (node is your SwingNode).
I used mouseReleased to mimic the same behavior as the standard FX nodes.